# Javascript Regex to validate string length and last 3 characters as digits

Tags: javascript, regex

How should I write regex to validate below conditions:

- Total length of string should be between 4 to 6
- Last 3 characters should be digits only.
- String is only alphanumeric

eg: Valid strings: 1234, EC123, 1YC898, 001234

So far, I have tried below regex, but seems like I am missing something?

```
(^[a-zA-Z0-9]{4,6})?\d{3}$
```

Comment: https://www.debuggex.com is great for trying your pattern and seeing why it works, or not, when you change it. The question is: what are you *really* trying to match. Is this homework with nonsense strings, or are you actually trying to find real strings from real data that need to match a specific pattern?

Comment: Thanks for the link Mike. I am using http://www.regexr.com/. This is for one of my SAP UI5 application. Need to set a validation regex for one of the input field.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,3}\d{3}$
```

- `^[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,3}` will match 1 to 3 alpha-numerals at the start
- `\d{3}$` will match 3 digits at the end of your input